# Proof of Dirac delta function identity involving exponential

Tags: limits, dirac-delta

Is the identity

$$\delta(x-a)=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \epsilon}}\exp{[-\frac{1}{2\epsilon}(x-a)^2]}$$

correct? If yes, what is the proof?

Comment: There are many ways to define $\delta(x-a)$ and all are equivalent.

Comment: It is correct. Firstly the area under the second function is always $1$ for all $\epsilon\gt0$. Secondly, every point on the second function goes to $0$ as $\epsilon\to0$ except the point where $x=a$ which goes to $+\infty$.

Comment: Great. Thus, the requirement for unit integral is met for any $\epsilon$ and the requirement for infinity at $a$ and $0$ everywhere else is met only when the limit $\epsilon \to 0$ is used.

Answer (score 1):

Pretend for the moment that $a = 0$. Show that these functions give a family of approximate identities, that is, a family $(f_n)$ of functions that

1. All integrate to 1,
2. Have uniformly bounded $L^1$ norm, and
3. Satisfy $$\lim \limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{\vert x \vert > \epsilon} \vert f_n \vert \rightarrow 0$$ for all $\epsilon > 0$. It is not quite sufficient that the $f_n$ converge *pointwise* to zero away from the origin.

(In fact, any nonnegative $L^1$ function rescaled in the way you describe will give such a family.)

A family of approximate identities will act as a delta function when integrated any sufficiently nice function, such as the smooth, compactly supported functions. That is, they will satisfy $$\lim \limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int f_n(x) g(x) \, dx = g(0)$$ for such $g$.

Comment: Well it depends on which family of test function you are going to integrate $f_n$. If it is $C^0,C^0_c,S,C^\infty_c$ you'll need different properties for $f_n$. What you said is the sufficient/necessary condition for $f_n \to \delta$ in the strong dual of $C^0\cap L^\infty$. The DCT is that the $f_n$ are bounded and $\to 0$ pointwise on $|x| > \epsilon$ is sufficient for $f_n 1_{|x| > \epsilon} \to 0$ in the dual of $L^1_c$.